# android java API email

Tags: android

Well am  building this app, now am at the point where I wanna use the java email API to send email, but am getting a few error such as "The import javax.mail cannot be resolved" I really tried everything here but cant seem to fix it .
if anyone could help I would really appreciate it.. am using eclipse by the way..

Thanks

Comment: You can use Java Mail API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-app

Answer (score 2):

Android does not include the javax libraries.

To send email on android app you would have to create an intent and let the email app handle it. Here is an example I found via a quick google search http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-send-email-your-application.